# Maven groovy compilation fails without explaining why

Tags: maven, groovy

I run

```
$ mvn clean compile
```

And get the folliwing output:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                        
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building tendiwa-core 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ tendiwa-core ---
[INFO] Deleting /home/suseika/Projects/tendiwa/core/target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.3:resources (default-resources) @ tendiwa-core ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ tendiwa-core ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Using Groovy-Eclipse compiler to compile both Java and Groovy files
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] COMPILATION WARNING :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] Found 0 errors and 0 warnings.
[INFO] 1 warning
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.439s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Jul 12 15:26:53 YEKT 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/154M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project tendiwa-core: Compilation failure
[ERROR] Found 0 errors and 0 warnings.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

There clearly is an error with the `maven-compiler-plugin`, but for some reason it doesn't say what exactly is the error. Running with `-e` flag doesn't explain anything either. What can be the cause of this?

Update:

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>
    <groupId>org.tendiwa</groupId>
    <artifactId>tendiwa-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
                        <version>2.8.0-01</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
                        <version>2.1.5-03</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Snapshots</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jgraph</groupId>
            <artifactId>jgraph</artifactId>
            <version>5.13.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.trove4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>trove4j</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jgrapht</groupId>
            <artifactId>jgrapht-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jukito</groupId>
            <artifactId>jukito</artifactId>
            <version>1.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vividsolutions</groupId>
            <artifactId>jts</artifactId>
            <version>1.14-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>15.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.la4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>la4j</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>kendzi.math</groupId>
            <artifactId>kendzi-straight-skeleton</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.10-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.tendiwa</groupId>
            <artifactId>twakStraightSkeleton</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice-assistedinject</artifactId>
            <version>4.0-beta4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>4.0-beta4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy.maven.runtime</groupId>
            <artifactId>gmaven-runtime-1.6</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-all-minimal</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.combinatoricslib</groupId>
            <artifactId>combinatoricslib</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jgrapht</groupId>
            <artifactId>jgrapht-ext</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


</project>
```

Comment: Running with debugging turned on (-X) might be informative.

Comment: My guess is your machine is pointing to old version of java please add java -version output

Comment: @BoristheSpider A bit too informative. What should I look there for? Should I post the whole huge log here? A quick search for `maven-compiler-plugin` in the `mvn clean compile -X` doesn't show anything interesting, just a bunch of debug messages.

Comment: I'm not convinced that the `groovy-eclipse-compiler` supports Java 8 yet - do you have evidence that it does?

Comment: @BoristheSpider I didn't even consider that to be an issue. Will check that. Why no error message then?

Comment: I would look at [this thread](http://groovy-eclipse-plugin.42567.n3.nabble.com/Java-8-support-td4025546.html): it seems to imply that version `2.9.X` will have Java 8 support. Error messages in Maven are down to the plugin - you'll have to ask the eclipse people...

Comment: @coreJavare You're right, `java -version` showed 1.7. I did update $JAVA_HOME to /usr/bin/java-8-oracle, but forgot to `update-alternatives --config java` and same for `javac`. However, even after `java` and `javac` are changed to 1.8, I still see the same build failure.

Comment: Groovy didn't support targeting JDK8 until 2.3.3 (http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-6850), and as @boris-the-spider mentioned, you have to wait for 2.9.0 to get access to the 2.3 branch code.  <shamelessPlug>If you don't want to wait, you might consider http://gmavenplus.codehaus.org/. </shamelessPlug>

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I managed to get this working with the following configuration:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0-01</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.4-01</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.0-01</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
</plugin>
```

Older versions do not support Java 1.8 and newer Groovy.

Comment: This issue makes me go crazy. Not even telling whats the problem it is simply failing. Thanks a lot my friend. Your solution worked like a charm.

Comment: Note that I had an issue where my groovy project depended on a Java API jar file (of my own), and did not compile due to crazy compiler errors I knew were wrong.  This solution fixed it and those errors went away.

Comment: Tried to use your configuration and many others but still getting: Execution default-compile of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile failed. (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile:default-compile:compile) AND Execution default-testCompile of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile failed. (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile:default-testCompile:test-compile) in eclipse, but using maven on command line is ok

Comment: @tomasb, that is a different problem, try to post a separate question. Or, as mvn works on the command-line, try to find the difference between pure maven compilation and eclipse one.