# I am unable to bulid Maven Project

Tags: maven-3, java-ee-7, wildfly-8

Please I am very new when comes to maven project and wildfly (JBoss) Server. I have a Java EE 7 project which I developed with NetBeans for Apache Tomcat 8. For some good reason I want to migrate to WildFly 8.

I have recreated the project on JBoss Studio 7.1 with all the Maven Dependencies. First attempt to run the project returns "Forbidden".

I tried to be sure the project is complied and deployed by running

```
mvn clean package
Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building ProjectName 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ ProjectName ---
[INFO] Deleting /path/to/the/ProjectName/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ ProjectName ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ ProjectName ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 74 source files to /path/to/the/ProjectName/target/classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.062 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-11-18T10:58:47+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/150M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project ProjectName: Compilation failure -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I re-run the command with -e

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project nants: Compilation failure -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project nants: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:582)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:129)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
[ERROR]
```

These tips contains my environment

```
Apache Maven 3.2.3 (33f8c3e1027c3ddde99d3cdebad2656a31e8fdf4; 2014-08-11T21:58:10+01:00)
Maven home: /path/to/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_20, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/oracle_jdk_8/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.16.0-24-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

I read the suggested [wiki](http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException) but could't solve the issue still. Maybe because I am still new.Please I will appreciate your help on resolving this errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found what problem for failed compilation was, I have fixed that by correcting my POM.xml  there was an error on my JAVA_HOME settings. though I am still getting "Forbidden" from the url which will need a different question thread if I am unable to resolve it.

```
<maven.compiler.executable>/absolute/path/to/bin/javac</maven.compiler.executable>

TO:

<maven.compiler.executable>${JAVA_HOME}/bin/javac</maven.compiler.executable>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using Java 8, please try on Java 7 as some components may not support Java 8.
Similar problem is described here: [maven-compilation-fails-without-explaining-why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24711651/maven-compilation-fails-without-explaining-why)

Comment: Thanks @Ostap I finally found what problem was, I have fixed that by correcting my POM.xml <maven.compiler.executable> there was an error on my JAVA_HOME settings. though I am still getting "Forbidden" on the url which I think i might need ask as a different question if I wasn't able to resolve it myself